# How to allow Phonegap to use geolocation (permission)

Tags: xml, cordova, permissions, geolocation, phonegap

I've created a **Phonegap App** which shows **the users current position**.

During the simulation of the app everything works fine, but after the compiling it doesn't works no more.

When I install the App on my Smartphone, no permissions are required. So I guess that's the problem. The geolocation plugin can't be used if there are no permissions for it?

So my question is, how to add the **permission for geolocation** to the **config.xml**? I've put a link to my config.xml below.

Thank you very much for answering, and best greetings from Germany :-)

## **[The config.xml](http://www.nik-lochmann.de/phonegapapp/config.xml)**

Comment: are you testing on iOS or Android?

Comment: I'm testing on Android. But finally it works with the permissions below. Nur thanks :-)

Comment: The first two should be there already, geolocation plugin should add them

Answer (score 1):

Add to Manifest in Android :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

Comment: When I add this to my config.xml using CLI 9.0 Phonegap build gives em an error saying malformed config file

Comment: can you please share your config file